# ChessBase Nalimov tablebases

Tags: engines, tablebases

I'm using Nalimov tablebases with Fritz14 and it basically works. Just one strange problems occurs: The engine doesn't mate because the final mating move isn't sorted correctly. It look like this:

```
+- (#2) move1
+- (#2) move2
= (0.00) move3
= (0.00) move4
# (#0) move5  (mating move)
```

I've tried to replace/rename TBAccess.dll several times as mentioned somewhere else, but the programm won't start, just displaying the message "TBAccess.dll seems to be corrupted".

Any ideas? Does it work with older ChessBase products only?

Comment: Where did you get the tablebases? Did you download them, and could they be corrupt somehow? Did they ever work? Is it just this one position, or you have confirmed it never does it? Post a picture of your tablebase options for the Fritz program.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Fritz 14 is capable of reading the newer Syzygy format tablebases.  Certainly the latest Fritz can.

These tend to take up less space than Nalimov format, which used a simpler compression scheme designed for the benefit of older computers.  For example, the 5-man tablebases take over 7GB in Nalimov format but under 1GB in Syzygy format.

So I suggest trying Syzygy before giving up.